# Cannot send single email via apex

Tags: apex

I have an issue where I can able to send and email via the 'execute anonymous apex' with no issues, but when I am doing this from my code I cannot get it to send. Also  using System.debug I can see that the program is entering my email class and when I query the mail object it is instantiated and populated with all the correct values but just wont seem to send?

So I can send this from the 'execute anonymous apex' - the email sends no problem

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'davidleckenby@gmail.com'};
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
mail.setReplyTo('davidleckenby@gmail.com');  
mail.setSenderDisplayName('Otters Pocket');
mail.setSubject('Test Subject');
mail.setPlainTextBody('Test Subject');
System.debug('mail1' + mail);
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

And this is the class that I created that I mentioned is being reached correctly, accepts the string parameter, instantiates the single email message, and even populates this with the values that I use here. However I cannot seem to get the email to send?

```
public class emailClass {
public void emailSend(String message) {
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'davidleckenby@gmail.com'};
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
mail.setReplyTo('davidleckenby@gmail.com');  
mail.setSenderDisplayName('Otters Pocket');
mail.setSubject('Test Subject');
mail.setPlainTextBody('Test Subject');
System.debug('mail1' + mail);
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
}
```

}

Also just to add I am calling this email class from an asynchronous future method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce Spring '13 introduced a new email deliverability setting (Setup > Email Administration > Deliverability). New sandboxes I believe are automatically set to "System email only," causing this error.

If this doesn't work, try calling the code synchronously.

Comment: Thanks Ohana - but it's set to 'all mail'

Comment: @DavidLeckenby I tried running your code when it's called from a trigger. Can you update your class is defined without sharing? so public class without sharing emailClass{...}

Comment: No joy with that either

Comment: Hmm... so here is what I would try...try moving it to a non asynchronous method and see if you can send it. If Also, in the future context what user is executing the future, Is it something weird like a site user? What do the debug logs say? Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you Ohana - that worked calling from a synchronous class/trigger.